# Public vs private network setting for macOS?

Tags: windows, networking, macos, firewall

On windows, we can set a LAN to be a public or a private network, to improve security.

Questions:

1. What does windows actually do (in terms of firewall settings) when I set a network to be private?
2. Does a similar setting exists on macOS/linux?
3. Does some third party tool implement this feature?